# Maven and Spring data storing

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm relatively new to these 2 frameworks that I have to use for a school project and I have a little curiosity. So far I have the CRUD Operations to add a new employee that has multiple attributes, to update an employee and delete him but I am not using a DB like Postgres, Oracle etc.So I am wondering where the actual data is stored because so far like I said I only have a class that saves the information in a HashMap but after the closing the application how come that the data is saved and where.
Sorry for the newbie question

Comment: Could you share some code? (the relevant parts - not the whole application)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. However, if you are not using a DB, your data might be saved into a file. When you put an object in a HashMap, you are keeping it in the memory and if you stop your application, the HashMap will be destroyed, unless you save it in a file or a DB. Please, provide more details.

Comment: @ThiagoProcaci that is the thing, i am not saving the data in any file.

Comment: Maybe Spring is saving in H2 database. Provide more details and we will better understand your question.